# Change action bar overflow icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have applied the following code in `values-v11` folder

styles.xml

```
 <style name="actionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/action_item_btn</item>
 </style>
```

But it not changing the overflow icon, all the other items in this theme is working fine but not this one, am i missing anything ?

Comment: you should have the styles in the respective res/values folders

Comment: but i want to apply these styles above 4.0 version

Comment: so in which values folder do you have the styles?

Comment: did you give a try and does it work??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 i want to apply these styles above 4.0 version
```

But you have the styles in `values-v11`

Also note

```
parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" // in your code
```

to

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" // mine
```

It should be in `values-v14`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
       <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>    
    </style>
</resources>
Snap
```

Forget how the ui look's this is for testing. But you see the launcher icon as the overflow menu icon.

[image]

Edit:

This is my test sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
             <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
              <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/red</item>
              <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:background">#FF9D21</item>

         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style> 
    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
           parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
      <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/launcher</item>    
    </style>
    <style name="ActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
</style>
</resources>
```

Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: ok, Got the point..Thanks alot..Also I want to add a divider at the end of action bar. I am using <item name=android:actionbardivider> but again it is not working

Comment: @Kanika that's a different question. to the question asked i have answered

Comment: I dont know why its not working on my side ? I have applied everything as you said

Comment: @Kanika i can only post what is working and what can work. I don't know how you are doing.

Comment: @Raghunandan Need to ask for what we need to place in values and values-v11 style files... Also I am getting IllegalException and getting suggestion on for to use Theme.Appcompat.

Comment: @AndroidHacker that is because you need to use AppCompat library and you should use AppCompat Theme. For values-11 see the docs its all there

Answer (score 1):

i think you should do the following :

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTheme.OverFlow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_overflow_image</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Kanika have the styles in values-v14/styles.xml and then try

Answer (score 0):

You can set it programmatically in Java like this:

```
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_icon, null));
```