# Getting Java.lang.NullPointException while getting ActionBar Title ID for inflating custom color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to get title Id of Action Bar so as to inflate color.

Trying same as undermentioned ..

```
   actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        int titleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
        actionBar.setTitle("Sign in or Create an account");
        yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.taxi_blue));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.white));
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

**This is working great in higher version but when I try same in lower version I am getting NullPointException**

I am getting exception at ..

```
yourTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.taxi_blue));
```

I have used back support library for same.

Really stuck on this.

Any hint on this is appreciated.

Comment: action_bar_title is not found in "lower versions".

Comment: So what should I use .. Any hint on this or any suggestion for how to use same.?

Comment: action_bar_title is not found in "lower versions".

Comment: @AndroidHacker why don't you deifne styles for title and set the color

Comment: @Raghunandan ..Yeah I tried that but failed :(.. Will be obliged if I get hint from your side

Comment: @AndroidHacker have the styles in respective res/values folder and it will work

Comment: are you using ABS or ActionBarCompact for backwards compatibility?

Comment: Actually when I tried using styles then stuff worked for lower versions but not for higher version. As I say that my background color was inflating in lower version but not on higher version. Thanks

Comment: @blackbelt .. Yup I am using same.

Comment: @AndroidHacker you probably din't have styles define for higher vesion in the respective res/values folder

Comment: @Raghunandan Might be you are right. Can you please guide me on this..

Comment: @blackbelt I am using back support library ..

Comment: the one that comes with the support library?

Comment: @AndroidHacker check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300920/change-action-bar-overflow-icon/21302679#21302679 has a example for higher version

Comment: Yeah .. Appcompat support library V7

Comment: @Raghunandan checking ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

action_bar_title is not found in "lower versions".

Since you are only changing the textcolor. You could probably be okay using:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>Sign in or Create an account</font>"));
```

Of course, replace `#ff0000` with your color defined by `R.color.taxi_blue`