# Android Action Bar Over Flow Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using Compat Actionbar to support Api 10. I have to extend my Activity by **ActionBarActivity**. By Extending to **ActionBarActivity**, my Action bar looks Like this.[image]

But I Need Action Button. If i Extend My Activity by simple **Activity** then it looks like this(My Actual requirment).[image]

Unfortunately to support Api 10 its compulsory to extend the Activity by **ActionBarActivity**.
 Any Idea, so that i can achieve my requirements using **ActionBarActivity**.

Here is my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_list"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_sort"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Use a custom icon for actionbar overflow icon

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you please elaborate..?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300920/change-action-bar-overflow-icon

Comment: It Requires Api Level 11.

Comment: Raghunandan is right and for supporting api level 10 , use sherlock Library of action bar.

Comment: Butt i am Already using Android Compat.

Comment: Modify it for below 11. Procedure same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved My Problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:packagename="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        packagename:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_sort"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        packagename:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Just Add Package name at some places as i mentioned.
Thanks.