# How to tint AppCompat r22.1 action bar overflow icon?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I know it's possible to **replace** the icon by setting a custom `actionOverflowButtonStyle` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300920/change-action-bar-overflow-icon). However, that style only allows setting a different drawable and or/background.

Instead, I would like to use the *standard* icon provided by AppCompat, just *tinting* it with a particular color, just as the drawer icon/back button can be tinted via the `color` attribute in `drawerArrowStyle`.

I have tried these methods, which reportedly used to work:

- Setting `colorControlNormal` -- [Toolbar icon tinting on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219178/toolbar-icon-tinting-on-android)
- Setting `textColorPrimary` in the theme -- [MenuItem tinting on AppCompat Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780046/menuitem-tinting-on-appcompat-toolbar)
- Setting a custom `actionBarStyle` and changing `colorControlNormal` there.

But as far as I can see none of them work with the latest AppCompat -- the overflow icon keeps its original color (while other widgets, such as TextViews or the text in menu items *do* change).

Should this be done differently now? I am not using a custom `Toolbar` view, just the default AppCompat-provided, ActionBar-like one.

---

How to reproduce:

1. Create a default Android Studio project, with minimum SDK version = 9.
2. This automatically includes a blank activity and a menu resource with a single menu item, "Settings", with `app:showAsAction="never"` which means it will be displayed in the overflow menu.
3. Finally, customize the `styles.xml` file. For example:

   ```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
           <item name="colorPrimary">#008888</item>
           <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
           <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff0000</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```

You'll notice that neither property affects the overflow menu icon color. Tested in a Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1.

Comment: [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: @karaokyo Done, though it's extremely easy to reproduce -- a default new Android Studio project is enough.

Comment: Oh, ok so it's the `DarkActionBar` forcing the white overlay. Don't use `DarkActionBar`?

Answer (score 2):

If you trace the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme, you see that it sets:

```
<item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
```

Which in turn inherits from `Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`, which sets:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
```

Which essentially equals white:

```
<color name="primary_text_default_material_dark">#ffffffff</color>
```

---

If you just inherit from `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light`, you won't run into this issue since it doesn't set the `actionBarTheme`. You can easily customize the action bar using the material properties anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this -- I had tried suppling an `actionBarStyle`, but not `actionBarTheme`.